# Writing a function to find if greater than 5 or less than 5

Tags: python, function

the question is:

Write a function, length, that takes in a list as the input. If the length of the list is greater than or equal to 5, return “Longer than 5”. If the length is less than 5, return “Less than 5”.

so far I have:

```
def length(x):
   for lst in x:
    if len(x) >= 5:
        return "Longer than 5"
    else:
        return "Less than 5"
```

Answer (score 6):

## Solutions:

Try using the below code:

```
def length(x):
    if len(x) >= 5:
        return "Longer than 5"
    return "Less than 5"
```

But if you want a shorter code, use:

```
def length(x):
    return '%s than 5' % ['Less', 'Longer'][len(x) >= 5]
```

Or use `str.format`:

```
def length(x):
    return '{} than 5'.format(['Less', 'Longer'][len(x) >= 5])
```

Or if your version is 3.6 or higher, use:

```
def length(x):
    a = ['Less', 'Longer'][len(x) >= 5]
    return f'{a} than 5'
```

@SayandipDutta helped out explaining it in a comment, he said:

"if `len(x) < 5` then it returns `False`, which is interpreted as `0`, and vice-versa for other condition, which evaluates to `1`. So, `['Less', 'Longer'][0]` or `['Less', 'Longer'][1]`."

## Why your code doesn't work?:

Your code doesn't work because `for` is iterating through `x`, and getting every value in `x`, however we want to match the length for the entire list, not every item's length.

Let's say your list is:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The below code:

```
print(len(x))
```

Will result in:

```
5
```

But if you use the below code:

```
for i in x:
    print(len(i))
```

It will raise an error.

Comment: I like the second solution. Could you explain `(['Less', 'Longer'][len(x) >= 5])` how this works, please?

Comment: if `len(x) < 5` then it returns `False`, which is interpreted as `0`, and vice-versa for other condition, which evaluates to `1`. So, `['Less', 'Longer'][0]` or `['Less', 'Longer'][1]`.

Comment: @SayandipDutta Yeah correct was ready to tell him that

Comment: Okay so invoking the for loop wasn't necessary at all. Thanks so much!

Comment: @ericksonss91 not only the `for` loop, you don't even need the `if - else` as @U10-Forward has shown in the second solution. Even in the first solution you do not need the `else` condition.

Comment: `But if you want a more efficient code`, could you explain how method 2 is more efficient than method 1?

Comment: @AjayDabas changed it to shorter

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
def length(lst):
    return "Longer than 5" if len(lst) > 5 else "Less than 5"
```